# Angular 1.5.9 Components: Functions fired when component is loaded

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-components

I am new to using the 1.5 components and I am not sure if what's happening is how components work or if I've just done something wrong. I have created the following component:

```
angular.module('app')
.component('appModal', {
    templateUrl: 'templates/modals/AppModal.html',
    controller: 'AppModalController',
    bindings: {
        resolve: '<',
        modalInstance: '<',
        close: '&',
        dismiss: '&'
    },
})
.controller('AppModalController', function() {
    var _this = this;

    this.submit = function() {
        this.close({ $value: this.data });
    };

    this.cancel = function () {
        this.dismiss('cancel');
    };

    this.$onInit = function() {
        this.data = this.resolve.data;
    };
});
```

So as you can see that I've created a modal component using ui-bootstrap component model. this works, however the function for closing/dismissing the modal are fired when the modal is opened, closing the modal immediately after the modal is opened. It seems that not only are the variables initialized but the methods are also when the component is loaded. I am not sure if this is how components work or if I am doing something wrong.

I followed the example on ui-bootstraps site (https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/). Any help and insight would be most appreciated.

UPDATE:

Turns that you can directly access the bindings in the view. They are automatically binded to the controller so you can use the alias (default alias is $ctrl) in the view and directly call $ctrl.close(). There's no need to tie them to a function in the controller of the component.

```
angular.module('app')
.component('appModal', {
    templateUrl: 'templates/modals/AppModal.html',
    controller: 'AppModalController',
    bindings: {
        resolve: '<',
        close: '&',
        dismiss: '&'
    },
})
.controller('AppModalController', function() {
    var _this = this;

    this.$onInit = function() {
        this.data = this.resolve.data;
    };
});
```

The above example is the re-factored component controller. I removed the methods that called the modal close and dismiss functions.

```
<div class="modal-header modal-header-color">
    <h3>My Modal</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <form>
       <label>Do form related stuff here</label>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="$ctrl.close()">Submit</button>
    <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="$ctrl.dismiss('cancel')">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

Notice above that you can just call the close and dismiss methods directly with the controller alias!!

NOTES: It matters not what you assigned "this" to, "this" will always bind to the controller. Example: var foobar = this; <-- foobar will still bind to the controller so the name of the variable that you assigned "this" to matters not :)

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle pls.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried pasting your code to the demo plunk and I couldn't seem to reproduce the modal auto-closing, however there are a couple of things you should consider

1. you didn't setup the `controllerAs` attribute, which means you will have to bind your controller `this` to `$ctrl` (similar to the demo plunk), if you wish to use `_this` then add

   controllerAs: '_this'

and later do

```
var _this = this;
```

and bind your methods to `_this`, not `this`

```
_this.cancel = function () {...)
```

or just avoid this using altogether by simply replacing `_this` with `$ctrl`

2. make sure you are not prematurely calling  `this.cancel` from your template or closing the modal some place else in the controller

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of usage of components. You can use vm for this.

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('example')
        .component('exampleInput', exampleInput());


    function exampleInput() {

        var component = {
            controller: ProActiveController,
            bindings: {
                exampleHint : '<'
            },
            templateUrl : 'components/example-input/example-input.html'
        };
        return component;
    }

    function ExampleInputController($scope)
    {
        /** inits */

        var vm = this;
        vm.clearButton = clearButton;
        activate();

        /** functions */

        function activate() {
           loadAuto();
        }

        function loadAuto() {

        }

        function clearButton() {
            vm.searchText = '';
        }
    }

})();
```